# Can I use "# of subjects" as "the number of subjects" in column headings in academic papers?

Tags: abbreviations

I'm now writing an academic paper.

To keep a table column short, I want to abbreviate the heading "the number of subjects" as "# of subjects."

I saw such an abbreviation somewhere, but I don't know if it's an appropriate expression for papers.

Is it okey to use such an abbreviation?

Comment: I think you should ask people who have published papers in the field/journal that your paper is aimed for. Is there anyone like that you can think of? Such a person would also be helpful in a lot of other ways.

Comment: Why do you think you might not be able to? And what does your style guide say?

Comment: Wouldn't "Subjects" be sufficient? In almost all such contexts, the implied (and inferred) meaning  "number of subjects" is pretty certain.

Comment: Use of # for number is very common in the U.S. But academic papers should probably be written for a world-wide audience, and I don't think this is widely used in international English. *"No. Subjects"* should be understood worldwide. Or you could use the [more international number symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign#English) №.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://www.nwrc.usgs.gov/techrpt/sta16.pdf) to a set of abbreviations. This particular document discourages the use of "#" as an abbreviation for *number* (page 107), but the notation *#subjects* is fairly clear, particularly if you provide the expanded form in a footnote.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the useful document. To make the meaning clear, I decided to refrain using the number sign.